# A couple wake up to find their house surrounded by a wall, stuff starts oozing out of the fireplace

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a sci-fi anthology(?) program where a couple wake up to find their house surrounded by a wall and there is slimy stuff coming out of the fire place.

The ending shows the house is in an oven and the couple are humans being held as pets by aliens. The slimy stuff is a melting candy bar.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've tagged this "movie" but you talk about "a program;" was this a movie or a tv show?  Also, when and where did you see it?  Was it live-action or animated?

Comment: @DavidW - OP mentioned that it was part of a scifi anthology but you edited that out :-)

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @Valorum Ah, oops.  Thanks for catching that.  I guess I should have retagged with [tag:tv].

Comment: @DavidW "was this a movie or a tv show?"   It was a TV Movie, or a movie-length episode of an anthology.

Answer (score 8):

Could this be [Child's Play](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088909/), an episode of Fox Mystery Theater?

> A family awakens to find themselves trapped in their own home, all
> windows and doors sealed by impenetrable walls. They desperately try
> to escape but everything fails. Then the wife notices a bizarre
> pattern.
>
> Ending here;

Comment: Definitely the correct answer.  The OP misremembers slightly. The family are dolls, mini robots with AI, the playthings of a human child in the future.  @Giacomo1968, yes, Hammer House was retitled for US broadcast.